# "element does not exist in cache" error upon radio button select using mechanize::phantomjs

Tags: html, perl, phantomjs, mechanize, browser-automation

I'm trying to automate a webpage that includes a lot of javascript functions in Perl. So far I've been successful by using the headless mechanize::phantomjs toolkit, but I can't get past this, probably, trivial error. I see a page with a menu of radio buttons and when I try to select any one of those using

```
$mech->set_fields('booking_choice' => "$i");
```

where $i is my iterator and 'booking_choice' is the name of the button, I get the error listed below. This is how it looks on the page:

```
<tr bgcolor="white">
   <td>
      <input type="radio" name="booking_choice" value="1">
   </td>
   <td class="tableTxt">
      Friday, January 16, 2015</td>
   <td class="tableTxt">
      08:45 a.m.</td>
   <td class="tableTxt">
      45 minutes</td>
</tr>
```

There are two other radio buttons with values 0 and 2, and that's what the iterator is for. However, within any one iteration upon selection of the button I get the following error:

```
Error while executing command: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request".....
```

I can locate the button on the page fine by using xpath and it always returns success:

```
if ($mech->xpath('//*[@name="booking_choice"]', one => 1)) {
      say "Success";
}
```

What I don't understand is:

1. Why the element is no longer accessible even when I can see it listed on the html source page.
2. How can I keep the Element intact so that it is available for selection.

I'm very new to webscraping, web automation and I found some similar question to mine on this forum but they are either written for ruby or use some other webdriver than phantomjs. I don't know how to implement any of the given solutions using mechanize::phantomjs. I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

I've placed the source HTML file here: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/948c5371

Comment: Is there a form around the radio buttons? Maybe you need to select  the form ([`$mech->form_*`](https://github.com/corion/www-mechanize-phantomjs)) before setting anything.

Comment: Yes, there's form around the buttons. I'll try your solution and post here. Thanks!

Comment: It works now! Thanks @ArtjomB. I selected the form with `$mech->form_name('name_of_form');` and then selected my desired radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mechanize requires you to select the form before you can set the form fields. This can be done with a variety of functions such as

- `$mech->form_name( $name [, %options] )`
- `$mech->form_id( $id [, %options] )`
- `$mech->form_number( $number [, %options] )`
- `$mech->form_with_fields( [$options], @fields )`

Taken from [here](https://github.com/corion/www-mechanize-phantomjs).

---

If this doesn't work, you can always run some custom code in the page context to change the fields. For radio boxes this would look like this:

```
$mech->eval(<<'JS', $i);
    document.querySelectorAll("[name='formName'] [name='radioButtonName']")[arguments[0]].checked = true;
JS
```

Although, this only changes the property of the radio button and in most cases this is enough. But sometimes there are event handlers on the DOM elements which will not be triggered in this case.

An alternative would be to actually use `$mech->click( $name [,$x ,$y] )` to click on the radio button and trigger all necessary events.

Comment: The next **problem** I've encountered in selecting the chosen radio button using `$mech->set_fields[$name => $value]` is that all radio fields have the same name. On the [Mechanize::PhantomJS](https://github.com/corion/www-mechanize-phantomjs) page, I can pass in an anonymous array but it is not working. I tried this: `$mech->set_fields('booking_choice' => [$i,$fieldnum]);` where $fieldnum is $i + 1 since fields are numbered from 1 and $i iterates from 0 to 3, say. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes! using the javascript function to move the radio button to the desired choice works beautifully. A lot of people have asked this very question but there was no help online. Your solution solves the problem very nicely!!